# PHP Kohana 3.2.2 multipart form $_POST not set on MAC but works on Win

Tags: windows, macos, post, multipartform-data, kohana-3.2

I've just encountered a weird problem. I've recently developed a medium size website using Kohana 3.2.2 + jquery + html + WAMP on Windows 7 platform. And everything seems to be working fine, until someone tries accesing the page from Mac platform. It seems that when sending some data with files in multipart form the global variable $_POST is not set, even though when debugging the data in web browser i'm able to see that DATA IS SET :| it's just not accesable by the controller with any $_POST or request->post(). I'm repeating, everything works perfectly when user is accesing page from Windows platform (tested on few separated clients), but not working when accesing from Mac platforms (tested on few separated clients).
It's killing me...
Example of what im trying to do:
**In View:**
user puts data into inputs (text and file types). Data is being send by form with enctype = multipart/form-data to controller's action
**In controller:**
$post = request->post();
if($post['sometextinput'] != '') throws exception of unknown index 'sometextinput'.

Answer (score 0):

That's extremely odd. I use Kohana on a daily basis (I develop on a Mac) and have never had an issue like that. Could you post your controller and the view? I'll plug it into a dummy project and see if I can replicate the issue. If I can I'll do what I can to get it working.

EDIT:

Could it possible be an odd configuration issue?

Just for my own clarification.

You're submitting a form that contains input fields and one or more file uploads.
When viewing it on a Windows machine you can see that the data is set in $_POST or $request->post().
On OSX it's not viewable to the controller via $_POST or $request->post();

In your before method make sure you have "parent::before();". If you are already calling parent::before() try putting it as the first statement in your before() method. If that doesn't work try adding it as the last statement. It's a shot in the dark, but it's worth a try.

If you don't have a before() method then add one and call parent::before();.

Comment: I've managed to get it working. The problem was with uploaded file size. The max file size atribute wasn't set in .htacces file. I've added it and now everything is working fine. But thx for Your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you were just in a hurry to type up your example above but it actually should be:

```
#$post = request->post(); //wouldn't recommend doing this
if($this->request->post('sometextinput') != '') throws exception of unknown index 'sometextinput'.
```